# How to Get 3 digit country code from latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, geolocation, country-codes

Can anyone please tell me about how to get 3 digit country code (for example India-IND) from latitude longitude

here is my code for getting 2 digit country code

```
  latitude = gps.getLatitude();
  longitude = gps.getLongitude();
  geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
  addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 
  Country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
  String Country_code1=addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
```

Comment: http://country.io/iso3.json

Comment: String Country_code1=addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
What will you give in Country_code1?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do it:

```
address.getLocale().getISO3Country();
```

Here is more about [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) and [ISO3 codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Country()) and some more about country [codes](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm).